# Optimization MySQL near match query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a query like this (my real query includes additional joins and filters):

```
SELECT CustomerId, 
  if (username = '$username', 1, 0) +
  if (name     = '$name'    , 1, 0) +
  if (phone    = '$phone'   , 1, 0) +
  if (address  = '$address' , 1, 0) AS matches
FROM Customers
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The query takes a number of filters and compares it to customer information finding and returning the closest matches. My problem is this is very slow and this query is running on a huge database of with millions of customer records. At the moment were seeing execution times in the minutes.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might optimization this query or write a new query to preform a near match search?

Comment: Are the 4 fields: `username`, `name`, `phone`, and `address` indexed?

Comment: can you please provide the output from `show create table Customers`

Comment: @Drew the actual query isn't just using one table. It's joining to other tables which contain the specific customer info being searched on. There is maybe around 10 tables being joined to. I'll also note, all of the information being searched on and joined on is indexed

Comment: @user11406 Out of curiosity, how did the query times get this bad? Users must have been dealing with progressively slower query times for quite a while now.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The problem is more that there is a huge amount of customer data being searched on in a way that doesn't take advantage of table indexes.

Regular queries which filter by the primary key or table indexes are fine and typically return results in a faction of a second as you'd expect.

Comment: Caveat: _If there are `JOINs` you did not mention, then any answers may not apply._

Comment: Hi, any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

This should help but I'm not positive:

```
SELECT
    CustomerId, 
    if (username = '$username', 1, 0) +
    if (name     = '$name'    , 1, 0) +
    if (phone    = '$phone'   , 1, 0) +
    if (address  = '$address' , 1, 0) AS matches
FROM Customers
WHERE username = '$username' OR // at least one of these columns should match or else we don't care about this record, right?
      name     = '$name' OR
      phone    = '$phone' OR
      address  = '$address'
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 50
```

This query assumes that you do not care about records which match zero of the criteria so MySQL can efficiently use it's indexes in the `WHERE` clause and you only have to calculate the `matches` score on records which match at least one search criteria.

---

*Obligatory note about* "Your code is prone to MySQL injection, blah, blah, blah"

Comment: I tried this already. It does seem to help a little (around 10% faster), but it's not enough to make the query feasible

Comment: @user11406 It's quite possible you are pushing the limits of a single MySQL instance and might need to get more sophisticated in your storage needs; check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/14733561. Also, are you running on SSDs already?

Answer (score 0):

The original query requires a table scan.  The version with `OR` also does.  No index would help either formulation more than a little.  Since your table is large, turning `OR` into `UNION` should work well:

```
SELECT CustomerId, SUM(ct) AS matches FROM (
( SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM Customers Where username = '$username' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM Customers Where name = '$name' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM Customers Where phone = '$phone' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM Customers Where address= '$address' )
)
GROUP BY CustomerId
ORDER BY matches DESC LIMIT 50;
```

It will need these 4 indexes:

```
INDEX(username, CustomerId),
INDEX(name,     CustomerId),
INDEX(phone,    CustomerId),
INDEX(address,  CustomerId)
```

Each sub-SELECT will very efficiently scan a tiny part of the corresponding index, write a very few rows to a tmp table.  Then the outer `SELECT` will do the sort (very likely to be in RAM, so ignore "filesort" in `EXPLAIN`) and deliver up to 50 rows.

And, yes, watch out for SQL Injection; it could destroy your server.